# Java tictactoe. Don't know how to continue

Tags: java

Need help to contniue the game! I want a tic tac toe i the command line. I am now stuck how to place X and O in the game. for exemple i want to by just press 1 it will change to and "x" or an "o". in the command Promt. I am also want to know how i should declare on a player's turn in the game. 
 thx all for your time. sorry for my bad english.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    public class TicTacToe{
      public static void main (String[] args){



        Scanner keyboard;
        Scanner input;
        String answer;
        int whereToPlace;
        char playerX = x;
        char playerO = o;

      System.out.println ("wanna play? (Yes/No)" );
      keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
      answer = keyboard.nextLine();

      while (answer.equals("yes")){

      }
      System.out.println("Pick a square");
    // skapa brädet i en 2D array
    String [][] board = { {"1", "2", "3"},
                        {"4", "5", "6"},
                        {"7", "8", "9"}
                        };

    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
      // För varje vektor i vektorn newBoard...
      for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print( "[ " + board[i][j] + " ]" + "\t");
      }
      System.out.println("\n");
    }

    System.out.println("Player x turn ");
    input = new Scanner (System.in);

      }
    }
```

Comment: Your _bad english_ is no real problem. But the lack of a proper problem explanation is. Where exactly are you stuck? What specific problem do you have? As it is, this question is unclear (and maybe a bit too broad).

Comment: What's with the indentation?

Comment: i want to for exemple by just press 1 it will change to and "x" or an "o". in the command Promt

Comment: Please do not add information in comments, but edit your question. And, please, correct your indentation.

Comment: sorry new at this webbside. will do it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll help with understanding the logic behind such game and give you the testing code but advice you to do it on your own.

First, you'll need a flag to tell you if the game is finished.

When does the game finish? 2 possible answers :

- One of the players wins
- The cells are all full without any winner

That will be what you'll be testing in your `do{}while()` loop

After that, you'll need to fill an array each time a player makes a move.

You'll have to be attentive to two things here :

- Number entered is an index of the array
- The number entered has not been played before

First condition is easy but for the second you'll need a way to "stock" the plays already made by both players.

At the end of your loop, you'll have to check if the game is finished and change your boolean if so.

How does someone win tic tac toe? By having an horizontal, vertical or diagonal set of the same character. You'll have to test all the possibilities and change your flag if filled.

Otherwise, if your board is entirely filled, you'll have to check that and break from the loop.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe{

    private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main (String[] args){

        boolean finished = false;
        int plays = 0;
        int position = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> alreadyPlayed = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] board = {"_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_"};
        String character;

        do{
            character = plays % 2 == 0 ? "x" : "o";
            do{
            System.out.println("Player " + character + ", it's your turn. (0-8)");
            System.out.println("Already played :" + alreadyPlayed.toString());
            position = scan.nextInt();
            } while (position >= 9 || alreadyPlayed.contains(position));
            alreadyPlayed.add(position);
            board[position] = character;
            if (alreadyPlayed.size()>=5){
                finished = checkFinished(board);
            }
            plays++;

            for (int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++){
                System.out.print(board[i]);
                if ((i+1) % 3 == 0) System.out.println();
            }

        } while (!finished && plays < 9);
        if (checkFinished(board)) System.out.println("Players " + character + " wins !");
        else System.out.println("No one wins.");


    }

    private static boolean checkFinished(String[] toCheck) {
        // Horizontal checks
        if (!toCheck[0].equals("_") && toCheck[0].equals(toCheck[1]) && toCheck[0].equals(toCheck[2])) return true;
        if (!toCheck[3].equals("_") && toCheck[3].equals(toCheck[4]) && toCheck[3].equals(toCheck[5])) return true;
        if (!toCheck[6].equals("_") && toCheck[6].equals(toCheck[7]) && toCheck[6].equals(toCheck[8])) return true;

        // Vertical checks
        if (!toCheck[0].equals("_") && toCheck[0].equals(toCheck[3]) && toCheck[0].equals(toCheck[6])) return true;
        if (!toCheck[1].equals("_") && toCheck[1].equals(toCheck[4]) && toCheck[1].equals(toCheck[7])) return true;
        if (!toCheck[2].equals("_") && toCheck[2].equals(toCheck[5]) && toCheck[2].equals(toCheck[8])) return true;

        // Diagonal checks
        if (!toCheck[0].equals("_") && toCheck[0].equals(toCheck[4]) && toCheck[0].equals(toCheck[8])) return true;
        if (!toCheck[2].equals("_") && toCheck[2].equals(toCheck[4]) && toCheck[2].equals(toCheck[6])) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, come on. That may be a homework or some sort of assignment. Why do it for him and not help him understand what he's doing wrong? Why don't you provide any explanation of any sort?

Comment: thx man. I understand a lot better to do now. CHEERS

Comment: @silversoul You're welcome, do not forget to validate the answer + here's a tip : before coding, try to imagine what the algorithm of your program will be using a sheet of paper and a pen.. It will help a lot I promis

Comment: will do. i only start java 2 weeks ago. thx again

Comment: No problem @silversoul. Do not forget to validate the answer :) So everyone knows you're pleased with it

Comment: @silversoul:  If YassinHH's answer solved your problem (or at least set you on the right path), please [mark his or her answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).  It marks your question as "answered", which is useful to future readers, and it rewards the person who answered the question.