# Console tic tac toe

Tags: java, console-application, tic-tac-toe

Alright, I've gone through some of the previous questions like this and it didn't really help me as most were using java swing and other things that are way out of my league. All I need is a functional console based tic tac toe, but I don't want to copy+paste finished code. 
   So far I'm stuck at the last method, makeMove. It's now asking for coordinates and saving the input in the variables row & col, but then what? How to make the move appear on the board?
Also, it doesn't like that I use row & col again in the next loop, so I'm not really sure what to do there either.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TTT {

    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int counter;
    static String player1, player2;
    static boolean gameOver = false;
    static char[][] board = new char[3][3];
    static char playerMarker;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        setupPlayers();
        printBoard();
        setupBoard();
        makeMove();
    }

    public static void setupBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                board[i][k] = ' ';


    }

    static public void printBoard() {
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(board[0][0] + "   |" + board[0][1] + "   |" + board[0][2]);
        System.out.println("-----------");
        System.out.println(board[1][0] + "   |" + board[1][1] + "   |" + board[1][2]);
        System.out.println("-----------");
        System.out.println(board[2][0] + "   |" + board[2][1] + "   |" + board[2][2]);

    }

    public static void setupPlayers() {

        System.out.print("Player1, what's your name?: ");
        player1 = keyboard.next();
        System.out.print("Alright " + player1 + ", who's Player2?");
        player2 = keyboard.next();
        System.out.print(player1 + " versus. " + player2 + ", good luck!");
    }

    public static void makeMove()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a row and a column: ");
        int row = keyboard.nextInt();
        int col = keyboard.nextInt();

        while (board[row][col] != ' ')
        {
            System.out.println("\nCoordinates already in use. Please try again: ");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java tictactoe. Don't know how to continue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677756/java-tictactoe-dont-know-how-to-continue)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of (if i undestand)

```
public static void makeMove()
{
    System.out.println("Enter a row and a column: ");
    int row = keyboard.nextInt();
    int col = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (board[row][col] != ' ')
    {
        System.out.println("\nCoordinates already in use. Please try again: ");
       return;
    }
    board[row][col] = 'X' ... or '+' please code 
    printBoard();


}
```

EDIT: Joop say about computer move, my answer is correction to user move. Yout work is to collect code together :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however it can't convert from int to char. Would the simple solution be to just make my board array an int?

Comment: Dont understand/ Why suppose int is required?

Comment: Because this happens when I try to run the code:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to char[]

Comment: 17 (where it calls for makeMove in the main method) and 58:                       board[row] = row;

Answer (score 0):

The following `break`s out the for-loop, using a freely named label `loop`.
Normally one should not use labels, but here it seems natural.
You could not break, but search for the best (i, k).

```
boolean found = false;
loop: for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        if (board[i][k] == ' ') {
            found = true;
            row = i;
            col = j;
            break loop;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "you could not break, but search for the best (i, k)."? I think I understood the code and if it works it really is very simple yet effective, however I have no idea what you are saying about labels and breaks and stuff :/ Thanks for the answer though, I really do appreciate it!

Comment: Joop write about "break" two level loop, must read some doc. One level loop is easy.

Comment: You also can do without break, and in the end-condition: `!found && i < 3` and `!found && k < 3`, so loop as long as not found.